# A section on my live wordpress site suddenly disappears, but still shows on localhost

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, rss

I currently handles a live wordpress site. It has a section that gets blog content from other website and works fine until just suddenly disappears all of sudden.

Meanwhile I also have the same wordpress website implemented on localhost for any trial and error. The section that disappear on live site works just fine on my localhost one.

I checked and the PHP coding are the same on both sites (the localhost was a copy of the live one). I'm new to the whole thing.

What I've done checked:

1. Comparing the related php coding between localhost and live (they
   are the same and no changes)
2. Implementing database from live to local (localhost still shows the section)
3. Activate the same plugins with the live one along with the plugin versions (I tried to figure
   if plugin causing this, so if i activate the same plugin causing error on live, i assume the local one would get this as well. But no changes)

Again, I'm new at this. I'm open to any suggestion on how to check what causing this